# Can't connect php to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I can't seem to get my php script to run properly. The problem occurs at the line:

`$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');`

I granted privileges to user 'user' for the database 'database.' I checked my list of users and 'user' is connected to localhost. I tried switching to the admin user that created the database but that doesn't work either.

If you have any idea as to what's wrong I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you mixed PDO connection method and mysqli methods.
the right syntax for the **mysqli** is:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','db_user','password','db_name') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just changed it but it still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Have you got any error lines as output that says where something is wrong?